# google colab, cv2_imshow throws error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clip'

Tags: python, opencv, google-colaboratory

I am learning the basics of OpenCV and while running the following piece of code in google colab, it gives an error.

```
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import cv2
img=cv2.imread("geeks14.png")
cv2_imshow(img)
```

The error is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-569c91be5363> in <module>()
      2 import cv2
      3 img=cv2.imread("geeks14.png")
----> 4 cv2_imshow(img)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/colab/patches/__init__.py in cv2_imshow(a)
     20       image.
     21   """
---> 22   a = a.clip(0, 255).astype('uint8')
     23   # cv2 stores colors as BGR; convert to RGB
     24   if a.ndim == 3:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'clip
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't `cv2_imshow`.

The issue is that `imread()` returned `None`. It could not read the given path as an image file.

Check the usual reasons for `imread()` failing, such as:

- file isn't there (look up what relative paths *are relative to*, or use absolute paths)
- file is corrupted
- file has a format that is not supported by OpenCV
- you don't have access rights
- system is broken in some way

Answer (score 0):

Please check in colab if file geeks14.png  is present there or not. You need to upload
[Check sample SS here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJJ22.png)

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways to fix this.

1. Goto the image you uploaded on Google colab, align your cursor on it, 3 dots will show, scroll to copy path, copy this path and paste in your code.
2. This error is as a result of having your image in a path not defined. Don't upload in sample folder. When you click on the menu to upload files, right click and upload your image as a single file.